# First time click says form valid false and on second time click everything works in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, angularjs

Im using angular js for my application, im fetching data and using it for presetting values in form fields but for the first time cliks data is fetching and form validation says valid false pristine true but for the second time it works perfectly, only for the first time this happens

The links im clicking for the modal
[image]

[image]

but the second time it works fine

[image]

modal.html

```
<div class="modal-body" >
    <div class="row centered-form">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div ng-show="isUpdateCommodityBatch">
                    <span class="modalHeader">Update Commodity Batch</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-2x closeIconForModal" ng-click="closeUpdateCommodityBatchModal()"></i>
                </div>
                 </div>
                 <div ng-hide="isUpdateCommodityBatch">
                 <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="modalHeader">Update Commodity Batch</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-2x closeIconForModal" 
                    ng-click="closeUpdatedcommodityModal()" ></i>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div ng-show="isUpdateCommodityBatch">
                        <form name="UpdateCommodity" role="form" novalidate >
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <label>Commodity name</label>
                                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : UpdateCommodity.commodityname.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.commodityname.$pristine, 'has-success' : UpdateCommodity.commodityname.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.commodityname.$pristine}">
                                    <input  type="text" name="commodityname"  class="form-control input-sm" ng-value="selectedCommodityBatch.dc_commodity.commodity.name" ng-init="updateCommoditybatch.name=selectedCommodityBatch.dc_commodity.commodity.name" placeholder="commodity Name" ng-model="updateCommoditybatch.name" required>
                                    </div>
                                <div class=" col-md-12">
                                    <p class="help-block">
                                        <span ng-show="UpdateCommodity.commodityname.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.commodityname.$pristine">Commodity name is required.</span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <label>Commodity Batch ID</label>
                                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : UpdateCommodity.batchId.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.batchId.$pristine, 'has-success' : UpdateCommodity.batchId.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.description.$pristine}">
                                    <input  type="text"  ng-model="updateCommoditybatch.batch_id" ng-init="updateCommoditybatch.batch_id=selectedCommodityBatch.batch_id" ng-value="selectedCommodityBatch.batch_id" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="description" name="batchId" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class=" col-md-12">
                                        <p class="help-block">
                                            <span ng-show="UpdateCommodity.description.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.description.$pristine">commodity description is required.</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <label>Commodity Batch Price</label>
                                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : UpdateCommodity.commodityBatchPrice.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.commodityBatchPrice.$pristine, 'has-success' : UpdateCommodity.commodityBatchPrice.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.commodityBatchPrice.$pristine}">
                                        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="commodityBatchPrice"  class="form-control input-sm" ng-value="selectedCommodityBatch.price" ng-init="updatedCommoditybatch.price=selectedCommodityBatch.price" placeholder="commodity price" ng-model="updatedCommoditybatch.price" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class=" col-md-12">
                                        <p class="help-block">
                                            <span ng-show="UpdateCommodity.commodityBatchPrice.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.commodityBatchPrice.$pristine">Commodity Batch Price is required.</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <label>Commodity Batch Available Quantity</label>
                                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : UpdateCommodity.availableQuantity.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.availableQuantity.$pristine, 'has-success' : UpdateCommodity.availableQuantity.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.availableQuantity.$pristine}">
                                        <input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="updatedCommoditybatch.availableQuantity" ng-init="updatedCommoditybatch.availableQuantity=selectedCommodityBatch.available_quantity" ng-value="selectedCommodityBatch.available_quantity" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="available quantity" name="availableQuantity" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class=" col-md-12">
                                        <p class="help-block">
                                            <span ng-show="UpdateCommodity.availableQuantity.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.availableQuantity.$pristine">Available Quantity is Required.</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <label>Commodity Batch Minimum Order Quantity</label>
                                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : UpdateCommodity.minimumOrderQuantity.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.minimumOrderQuantity.$pristine, 'has-success' : UpdateCommodity.minimumOrderQuantity.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.minimumOrderQuantity$pristine}">
                                        <input type="number" name="minimumOrderQuantity"  class="form-control input-sm" ng-init="updatedCommoditybatch.minimumOrderQuantity=selectedCommodityBatch.minimum_order_quantity" ng-value="selectedCommodityBatch.minimum_order_quantity" placeholder="minimum order quantity" ng-model="updatedCommoditybatch.minimumOrderQuantity" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class=" col-md-12">
                                        <p class="help-block">
                                            <span ng-show="UpdateCommodity.minimumOrderQuantity.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.minimumOrderQuantity.$pristine">Minimum Order Quantity is Required.</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <label>Commodity Batch Expiry Date</label>
                                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : UpdateCommodity.expiryDate.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.expiryDate.$pristine, 'has-success' : UpdateCommodity.expiryDate.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.expiryDate.$pristine}">
                                        <input type="date"  ng-model="updatedCommoditybatch.expiryDate" ng-init="updatedCommoditybatch.expiryDate=selectedCommodityBatch.expiry_date" ng-value="selectedCommodityBatch.expiry_date" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="expiry_date" name="expiryDate" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class=" col-md-12">
                                        <p class="help-block">
                                            <span ng-show="UpdateCommodity.expiry_date.$error.required && !UpdateCommodity.expiryDate.$pristine">Expiry Date is Required.</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div class="row">{{UpdateCommodity.$error.required}}
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-block formSubmitButton" ng-disabled="UpdateCommodity.$error.required" ng-click="submitUpdateCommodityBatch(selectedCommodityBatch)">Update Commodity </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

call back function

```
    function showBatchDetails(){
      //getBatchDetails funtion sets the selectedCommodityBatch
    $scope.currentUserTypeForModals();
    $scope.isUpdateCommodityBatch=true;
    $scope.errorText="";
    $scope.updatedCommoditybatch = {};
    $scope.updateCommodityBatchModal= $uibModal.open({
      animation: false,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'views/CommonModals/updateCommodityBatchModal.html',
      scope: $scope,                
      size: 'lg',     
      show: true,
      keyboard: false,
      backdrop: 'static'    
    });
    }

    $scope.updateCommodityBatch=function(batch){
      getBatchDetails(batch.id, showBatchDetails())
  }
```

getBatchDetails()

```
function getBatchDetails(batch_id,callback) {
  var accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token')

  var form = {
    "batchId": parseInt(batch_id),
  };

  $scope.errorText = "";
  
  var request = {
    method:'POST',
    url: BASE_URL+'api/commodity/get-batch-details',
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    data:form};
    
  $http(request).then(function(response){
    console.log("respnse", response.data)
    if(response.data.status == 'success'){
      $scope.selectedCommodityBatch = response.data.commodity_batch
      if(callback){
        callback();
      }
      // callback(response.data.commodity_batch)
    }
  },function(error){
      $scope.successStatusInfo("Unknown error! Please try again.");
  });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.